# How many EC2 instances can be created for free tier account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using AWS free tier to create EC2 instances(OS: Linux). Its' root volumes must be greater than snapshot size. As far as I know, it should be bigger than 8 GB for Linux EC2. But I only have 30 GB EBS free volumes size.

Does it mean I can create 3 Linux EC2(8+8+8 < 30 GB) maximally?
Is there any way to get around the limit size of 8GB? For example, I would like to create 5GB EC2(Linux), So I can create 6 EC2 instances(30GB / 5GB = 6) with Linux.

ADD Volumes pic:

[image]

Comment: Please note that the [AWS Free usage tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is provided so that you can explore AWS services. It is not intended to be used for production purposes.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just do some test.

Answer (score 1):

You may create as many EC2 as you want, AWS will charge you by the time you keep them running.

If you check this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/), you'll see that AWS calculates the EBS pricing considering the time you keep it running:

> For example, let's say that you provision a 2000 GB volume for 12 hours (43,200 seconds) in a 30 day month. In a region that charges $0.10 per GB-month, you would be charged $3.33 for the volume ($0.10 per GB-month * 2000 GB * 43,200 seconds / (86,400 seconds/day * 30 day-month)).

Besides EBS, you must consider EC2 hours too. If you run `X` EC2 instances which support Free Tier by `H` hours, you won't be charged if `X*Y < 750` in a month period. For instance, if you have 3 instances, the maximum time you should run them is `750 / 3 = 250` hours in a month.

About the EBS size, I've never tried to decrease EBS size, but you may find some articles that explain how to to that: [link 1](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=151358) and [link 2](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-get-around-the-8gb-limit-on-root-volumes-in).

Comment: Thank you! I added pic of volumes, please check above pic link in my post. They are all root volumes for 3 EC2 instances. Total size of  provisioned volumes is 28GB. All instances are stopped. But Aws still charge me. I understand the length of time I provisioned for EC2. But for the root volumes, it is less than 30 GB, why it still charge me?  All of them are root volumes, I didn't expand any volume for EC2 instance.

Comment: I don't know why this happens to you. Won't you have insights if you check your billing? My billing for instance: `$0.00 per GB-month of General Purpose (SSD) provisioned storage under monthly free tier30 GB-Mo$0.00
$0.10 per GB-month of General Purpose SSD (gp2) provisioned storage - US East (Northern Virginia)23.871 GB-Mo$2.39`

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the prices using [AWS Calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).
To apply free tier, don't forget to enable the option on top `FREE USAGE TIER: New Customers get free usage tier for first 12 month`